# UIView width changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard with "Use Auto Layout" disabled and the following layout:

- View Controller Scene

  - View Controller (0,0,320,568) (W+H)

    - Table View (5,0,310,568) (W+H)

      - Prototype Cell (0,86,310,100) ()

        - Content View (0,0,310,100) ()

          - UIView (0,0,310,100) (W+H)

            - UIImage
            - UILabel

The problem is that when I close Xcode and reopen Xcode the UIView changes from (0,0,310,150) to (0,0,300,257). If i close and reopen Xcode again the UIView changes to (0,0,290,364) and so on (i.e. the UIView width is reduced by 10 and the height is increased by 107 every time). Closing and reopening the project has the same effect.

Any thoughts as to what is happening here?

Comment: r u using auto layout, if yes update the constarint

Comment: Did you try to delete your UIView and add another one? Xcode sometimes acts funny.

Comment: How you determine view frame? I mean are you run the application to check view frame or from Storyboard it self.

Comment: I'm not using auto layout. I tried deleting the UIView and adding another one but the new UIView is behaving the same way. I just noticed the height is changing by 107 as well. And you don't need to shut down Xcode, just closing the project and reopening the project does the same thing. I'm not even running the app.

Answer (score 0):

So I think Dani is right - sometimes Xcode acts funny. I added a new temporary View Controller Scene (VCS) and added the Table View and UIView manually (i.e. I didn't copy them like i did before). Now when I close the project and reopen it, the UIImage width and height on the new VCS change BUT the UIView of the original VCS remained unchanged - the bug transposed itself onto the new temporary VCS.

The good news is that I deleted the new temporary VCS and now when I close and reopen my project the original VCS remains unchanged.